# creating time array by half hour in select menu from time range RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, time

I have an appointment app where the user can set a first appointment time (@project.time_start) and last appointment time (@project.time_end).  I would like to create an array of times between these ranges (ie. 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30. etc)  so that I can use two select menus to select time start(11:00) and time end (11:30).  I know I can use timepicker....but the select menu would make for better UX.

I have been able to find an array of dates between a date range using this:

```
 @date_range_start =(@project.date_start.to_date .. @project.date_end.to_date)
```

But I'm stumped at how to translate that to time. The below code

```
 @time_range_start =(@project.time_start.to_time .. @project.time_end.to_time)
```

throws this error:

```
can't iterate from Time
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a timepicker, you can use `ActionView` [`select_time`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_time) helper directly in your view like this (*HAML*). Please notice the usage of the `minute_step` option:

```
= select_time @project.time_start, field_name: 'time_start',  minute_step: 30
```

If you have a Time range to constrain the selector, you can pass the limits (an array containing the start and end hours from the controller like this, for example: `@time_start = [8, 20]`) and use the `start_hour` and `end_hour` options:

```
= select_time @project.time_start, field_name: 'time_start', 
    minute_step: 30, start_hour: @time_start[0], end_hour: @time_start[1]
```